# Clarification on proof of $\tau_1 \times \tau_2$ is $T_2$ iff $\tau_i $ is $T_2$ for $i=1,2$

Tags: general-topology

**Proposition:** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space

(1)If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base of $\tau$ and $p \in X$ , the set $\mathscr{B}_p=\{ B \in \mathscr{B}\mid p \in B\}$ is base of neighborhoods of $p$

(2) If for every $p \in X$ is defined a base of neighborhoods $\mathscr{B}_p$, then the set $\mathscr{B}=\{B \in \mathscr{B}_p\mid p \in X \}$ is a base of $\tau$

**Theorem**

$\tau_1 \times \tau_2$ is $T_2$ iff $\tau_i $ is $T_2$ for $i=1,2$

The reverse implication is easy and I understand it. I have a problem with the forward implication:

> Let $p_1, q_1 \in X_1$ with $p_1 \neq q_1$, Now for any $p_2 \in X_2 $we have $p=(p_1,p_2) \neq q=(q_1,p_2)$. By the $T_2$ hypothesis, there exists $ U \in \mathscr{U_{p}}$ and $V \in \mathscr{U_{p}}$ with $U\cap V = \emptyset$.

> **Using the previous proposition , there exist $ U_1 \in \mathscr{U_{p_1}}, U_2 \in \mathscr{U_{p_2}},V_1 \in \mathscr{U_{q_1}}$ and $V_2 \in \mathscr{U_{p_2}}$, such that $U_1 \times U_2 \subseteq U$ and $V_1 \times V_2 \subseteq V$.        $(\alpha)$**

> So $(U_1 \times U_2)\cap (V_1 \times V_2)=\emptyset$. So necessarily  $U_1 \cap V_1 =\emptyset$ and so $\tau_1$ is $T_1$

**What I  don't understand is** $(\alpha)$, how are they using that proposition to imply the existence of $ U_1 \in \mathscr{U_{p_1}}, U_2 \in \mathscr{U_{p_2}},V_1 \in \mathscr{U_{q_1}}$ and $V_2 \in \mathscr{U_{p_2}}$, such that $U_1 \times U_2 \subseteq U$ and $V_1 \times V_2 \subseteq V$ ?

Comment: It's easier, IMO, to use that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic to subspaces of $X_1 \times X_2$. And subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are also Hausdorff,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may agree that the collection of all $U\times V$ for open subsets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ forms a basis of $X\times Y$. Hence we can see that the collection
$$\{U\times V\mid p\in U\text{ and } q\in V\}$$
is a local base of $(p,q)\in X\times Y$. Could you conclude $(\alpha)$ from this observation?

Comment: I agree with your first statement, the second one is using (1) of the proposition I mentioned, right? taking the neighborhoods of  (p,q) gives a local base for $U \times V$, am I right?

Comment: Still I don't see the conclusion

Comment: @mathlover Let me put your proof within different symbols. Let $p_1,p_2\in X$ such that $p_1\neq p_2$. Take any $q\in Y$, then you can find disjoint open sets $O_1$ and $O_2$ such that $(p_i,q)\in O_i$. From the mentioned local basis, take $U_i\times V_i$ such that $(p_i,q)\in U_i\times V_i \subseteq O_i$.

Comment: @mathlover We know that $B_{p,q}=\{U\times V\mid p\in U\text{ and } V\}$ is a local basis of $(p,q)$. We can apply this fact for $(p_1,q)$ and $(p_2,q)$. We can make $U_i\times V_i$, since $B_{p_i,q}$ is a *local basis* of $(p_i,q)$.